# Char array Segmentation fault

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am just playing around with a simple c code. I want to print all the days string in the days array pointer. However I am running to segmentation fault. The problem lies in the for loop. What am I doing wrong here. Thanks

```
main(){
  const char *days[] = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday",\
                        "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"};
  int i;

  for(i = 0; i < sizeof(days); ++i)
   printf( "%s\n", days[i]);
}
```

Comment: the `sizeof` operator returns a size in bytes, divide by `sizeof(*days)` to get the number of elements in an array

Answer (score 2):

```
int main(){
  const char *days[] = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday",\
                        "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"};
  size_t i;
  for(i = 0; i < sizeof days / sizeof days[0]; ++i)
   printf( "%s\n", days[i]);
}
```

`sizeof day` yield the size of the whole array, so you have to divide it with the size of one of its elements to get the number of element it contains.

Comment: thanks to all for help

Answer (score 2):

change the `for` statement to

`for( i = 0; i < ( sizeof(days)/sizeof(days[0]) ); ++i )`

The `sizeof` expression gives you the number of elements in the array, as opposed to the number of bytes it takes

A classic way to do this is a macro

`#define SIZEOF( X ) ( sizeof( X )/sizeof( X[0]) )`

and then use `SIZEOF` instead of `sizeof`